# cross cluster reindexing in solr?

Tags: search, solr

I have been using elasticsearch and there is a feature in it which allows reindexing of data from one cluster to another. Here is the sample api request for the same

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://oldhost:9200",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    "index": "source",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "test": "data"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest"
  }
}
'
```

Solr also has a reindex collection api : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/collections-api.html#reindexcollection
But in the above api the source and target names can be only collection names rather than remote index url's as per the doc. So does solr have an inbuilt cross cluster reindexing feature or will I have to write it using the provided solrj client maybe.
If there are any other workarounds for the same then please suggest.
One workaround that I can think of is the snapshot and restore kind of functionality where you can take the snapshot of a particular collection in cluster 1 and restore it in cluster 2. But this backup and restore approach has its own limitations as it wont allow a schema change or even a config change like the shards etc

Comment: The backup and restore API restores the cluster structure as well, so it'll require you to have the same set of nodes after restoring - it's more brute than reindexing / import from a different cluster/node: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/making-and-restoring-backups.html

Comment: There is also an entity processor available for DIH that allows you to use a different Solr instance as the source of the data: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor

Comment: thanks @MatsLindh . This will solve my case but I am running into some issue with it :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943301/solr-dih-showing-data-import-successfull-but-no-docs-retrieved-via-query